# FMOD play music streaming or is there another way

Tags: c#, fmod

So it seems you can stream on FMOD by doing something like

```
system.createStream() // with parameters   string name_or_data, MODE mode, ref CREATESOUNDEXINFO exinfo, ref Sound sound)
```

But then I see there is a music system

```
MusicSystem musicSystem = null;
_eventSystem.getMusicSystem(ref musicSystem);
musicSystem.loadSoundData(...)
```

What is the better approach and why?
I am using FMOD from C#

Answer (score 0):

The Music System is for creating interactive music in the FMOD Designer tool, System::createStream is for playback of a single audio file (which could be a piece of music).

It all comes down to what you need for your game.